# spring boot: change print console to json rest

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data

Actually, my project in Spring send values from the database via console, like this:
[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcDHY.png), but I want to send this values via JSON like a rest API, but I don't know how to change that.

```
{ 
"depositarios": {
"correo": "correo",
"nombre": "nombre",
"numTel": "numTel",
"pApellido": "pApellido",
"SApellido": "sAellido"
}
}
```

this is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication

@ComponentScan("com.abner.springpostgresql.service.impl, com.abner.springpostgresql.dao.imp")
public class SpringPostgresqlApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(SpringPostgresqlApplication.class, args);
        depoService depoService =context.getBean(depoService.class);
        depoService.loadAllDepo();
    }
}
```

this is my entired project source https://github.com/abnercoronado/restpostgresql

Comment: But you want to print the object as json in your console or return a json as a REST API?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza as a REST API

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I update my question with the source project.

Comment: I don't see the controller in your source code. Did you check my answer and tried that solution?

Comment: I've been following this [example](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/how-to-use-jdbc-template-with-spring-boot-for-postgres-database)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a RestController using the `@RestController` annotation like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/personas", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Persona> listaPersonas() {

        // This is just a sample. Here you could bring your data form your db
        List<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<Persona>();

        Persona p = new Persona();
        p.setNombre("angel");
        p.setEdad(20);
        lista.add(p);

        return lista;
    }
}
```

The value of the @RequestMapping annotation ("/personas" in this example) will be the endpoint. So when you access to the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/personas` (asuming that your app is running on http://localhost:8080) then you will get your data as json.

[Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) is an example of how to do it.

[Here](http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2015/03/servicios-restful-con-spring.html) is another example (en español) that could help you.

Comment: I recive this in the console [link](https://pastebin.com/vdC2iKyQ) and my localhost:8080 drop a error 404.

Comment: Please show your controller and the URL that you are trying to access

Comment: Sorry I don´t update my github, here is [my controller](https://pastebin.com/UYZu8Yi6), i only recive this [error message](http://imgur.com/OtKAZb6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper to convert your pojo or object to JSON String and send where ever you wanted using thier API or anything.

Or you can create Rest Method and Access the API would return you the Json Value.

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/depo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<?> getDepo() {

  ApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(SpringPostgresqlApplication.class, args);
    depoService depoService =context.getBean(depoService.class);
    List<?> lista = depoService.loadAllDepo();
    return lista;
}
```

Another way of doing.

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/depo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Depo> getDepo() {

  ApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(SpringPostgresqlApplication.class, args);
    depoService depoService =context.getBean(depoService.class);
    List<Depo> lista = depoService.loadAllDepo();
    return lista;
}
```

Once you start your server, you can run this by doing localhost:8080/depo. you can also return XML.

Comment: Where you get the value "lista" in the return?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: The only answer what I receipt from tomcat is an error 404.

Comment: Please share your code and what type of application is that? is it a spring boot or regular rest service?

Comment: This is [my controller](https://pastebin.com/GvYuvJiy), and my application is type spring boot.

Comment: OK. Do you have application.properteis? can you share it? and what URL have you tried?

Comment: I'm tried whit localhost:8080/lista also localhost:8080 and i receipt the same error, [this](https://github.com/abnercoronado/restpostgresql/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties) is my application.properties

Comment: is your application started? could you please share your console log output? 404 is when your api is not exist. Send me server console log as soon as you start

Comment: https://github.com/abnercoronado/restpostgresql is tis your soruce code? i dont see your controller class only

Comment: yes that is my source code, and this is my [console log](https://pastebin.com/GaABXAAw) and my [controller](https://github.com/abnercoronado/restpostgresql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/abner/springpostgresql/controller/controllerDepo.java)

Comment: try this.. localhost:9999//lista

Comment: in controller instead of RequestMapping, put GetMapping. Restart and try it.